# where is mapping function defined in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, mapping

In Play framework, my understanding is we use mapping function in Form to create object of type Mapping as follows:

```
Form(
    mapping(
      "name"->text
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply))
```

Where is the mapping function defined? I want to see its source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's defined as `play.api.data.Mapping`

You can go through the [API DOCS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Forms$@mapping%5BR%2CA1%5D((String%2CMapping%5BA1%5D))((A1)%E2%87%92R)((R)%E2%87%92Option%5BA1%5D)%3AMapping%5BR%5D)

Comment: I accept your answer as you have pointed me to correct page. mapping is defined in Forms object.